# Create duplicate Excel table which content is plain-text

Tags: microsoft-excel

How to convert tables with formulas to be "plain-text" for given Excel file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- select your table and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy it
- go to where you want to paste it and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to open the Paste Special dialogue
- select "Values" and click **OK**
- this will copy the displayed values of the source table, rather than the actual cell contents, effectively converting formulae to their values

[image]

Comment: If the data you copy contains dates, times, or numbers with fixed decimal place settings, and you're pasting to a new location, you probably want to choose "Values and number formats". (If you're pasting to a new location with no specific format information, then choosing Paste Special "Values" can cause dates and times to show up as numbers, or cause fixed decimal places to change to floating decimal places.) If you're pasting over the same data you just copied, then Paste Special "Values" is sufficient to remove the formulas, because the correct formats are already in place.